# Centos 5.01 can't connect to the internet

Tags: networking, centos

I am trying to download USB driver for centos 5.01  but I can't connect to the internet. I   have tried to set ONBOOT="yes" , NM_CONTROLLED="yes" and BOOTPROTO="dhcp" on  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file. But still it is not connecting. Below are my cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and cat /etc/sysconfig/network output respectively.

```
 DEVICE=eth0
 BOOTPROTO ="dhcp"
 NM_CONTROLLED = "yes"
 ONBOOT ="yes"
 ----------------------

 NETWORKING ="yes"
 NETWORKING_IPv6 ="no"
 HOSTNAME =localhost.local domain
 GATEWAY = 197.176.7.1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What mode are you using DHCP or MANUALLY!?

Comment: Is the 'network' service enabled?  Does `service network start` bring up the network?  WHy are you hard-codeing a GATEWAY if you are using DHCP?

Comment: I'm using DHCP.

Comment: Output of "service network start" Determining IP address for eth0.... failed.  Bringing up interface eth0-static.

Comment: I'm not hard coding Gateway anymore and still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The configuration file is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, not `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-etho`.  Similarly, the device name inside the configuration file must be `eth0`, not `etho`.</s>

<s>Inside the configuration file, the words to the left of the equals signs must be `ALL_CAPS`.</s>  There must be no space preceding or following each equals sign.

<s>That assumes that your USB Ethernet driver is working, which is far from certain.  If so, you should see that network device when you run `/sbin/ifconfig`.  If it's listed, but isn't named `eth0`, then you will need to rename and adjust your configuration file accordingly.  If you don't see any network device other than the `lo` loopback interface, then, well… you have a much more complicated problem.</s>

Comment: It is only a matter of misspelling. All the things you said are correctly displayed in the system. Sorry for that. And ifconfig lists eth0 but it does not have any ipaddress.

Comment: Please correct the question then, so that it shows exactly what is in your configuration file.